# cURL web scraping from VBulletin

Tags: php, curl, vbulletin

Hi need some help i am new to cURL,i am trying to scrap data from http://www.ugbettingforum.co.uk, 
so i can send any changes in forum to my e-mail.

But can't pass log-in. Forum is VBulletin and i manage to get massage "thanks for log in username" but after redirect i am not loged in.

here is my code:

```
function vBulletinLogin($user, $pass){
   $md5Pass = md5($pass);
   $data = "do=login&url=%2Findex.php&vb_login_md5password=$md5Pass&vb_login_username=$user&cookieuser=1";

   $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.ugbettingforum.co.uk/login.php?do=login"); // replace ** with tt
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '10');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $store;
curl_close($ch);}
```

Comment: Nope. It's not going to happen. There's a token that is generated each page load that is passed to verify you're not a bot. You should [look at the vBulletin documentation](https://members.vbulletin.com/api/) and script this properly instead of scraping with cURL.

Comment: you are saying that cURL is wrong approcah and it is not going to work.

Comment: plz use beautifulsoup version 4 - cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267564/login-to-vbulletin-forum-with-python