# Login to Vbulletin forum with python

Tags: python, vbulletin

I'd like to scrape a [board](http://ozbeceriksizler.com/login.php?do=login) which I am currently an active member of. But for this to happen I have to be logged in. I have seen various posts but did not understand the logic behind it. Also did not find a working solution.

This is the  [site](http://ozbeceriksizler.com/login.php?do=login) where I want to login.

I Understand that somehow I have to populate the password and username field and generate a md5hash password on the "flye". But I don 't have any clue how to start this. And do not understand what the login procedure looks like. My question is what do I have to do to figure this out. Which things do I need to take in consideration? How do I start? What are your overall recommondentions?

I am using Python 3.6 and I am a noob who tries to learn python.

My dear regards

Comment: You should include info on what scraping library you are using, since I'm sure that will change the answers you get. But really,  as far as I know, you should be using a stored authenticated session or cookie in order to be logged in. Having your script enter in credentials and log in itself seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I lean towards scrapy, but with almost zero programming skills it seems a tough learning curve, but I don't mind that. But if there is a simpler solution to get me logged in, I go for that. What library do you advice?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i Did Some Googling for your problem i found "Tonakai" who posted His script Login into a vBulletin Board it's a python 2 script u can easly use it on python 2 by making few changes This is the scipt :

```
    //
import hashlib
import requests

username = 'yourusername'
password = 'yourpassword'
BASE_URL = 'http://www.example.com'
session = requests.Session()
session.post(BASE_URL + 'login.php?do=login', {
'vb_login_username':        config.username, //vb_login_username is the variable vBulletin uses when you input your Username for logging in
'vb_login_password':        '',//Same for the password
'vb_login_md5password':     hashlib.md5(config.password.encode()).hexdigest(),//vBulletin uses MD5 encode
'vb_login_md5password_utf': hashlib.md5(config.password.encode()).hexdigest(),

'cookieuser': 1, //That allows you to stay logged in as a real nerd
'do': 'login',
's': '',
'securitytoken': 'guest'
})
```

Comment: The source : http://www.rivalgamer.com/threads/login-into-a-vbulletin-board-using-python-cookie-re-login-method.3082/

Comment: Thanks for the googling but thiscode did not do the job. There is no need to convert the code. Only problems are the // for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with another website. Based on Chamsddine107 solution this worked for me:

```
import hashlib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with requests.Session() as s:
    username = 'YOUR USERNAME'
    password = 'YOUR PASSWORD'
    BASE_URL = 'https://ozbeceriksizler.com'

    r = s.post(BASE_URL + '/login.php?do=login', {
    'vb_login_username':        username,
    'vb_login_password':        password,
    'vb_login_md5password':     hashlib.md5(password.encode()).hexdigest(),
    'vb_login_md5password_utf': hashlib.md5(password.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(),

    'cookieuser': 1,
    'do': 'login',
    's': '',
    'securitytoken': 'guest'
    })

    base_page = s.get('THE PAGE ON THE WEBSITE YOU WANT TO SCRAPE')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(base_page.content, 'lxml')
    print(soup)
```