# Perform a vBulletin-Forum login with Python

Tags: python, python-requests, mechanize, vbulletin

I want to perform a login to a vbulletin forum.

After the login you will be redirected to the mainpage. I want the content of a forum thread which is only visible, when logged in.

I found this question: [Login to Vbulletin forum with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267564/login-to-vbulletin-forum-with-python)

My code looks like this:

```
username = "testuser"
password = "testpassword"
try:
FORUM_URL = 'https://forumurl.com/forum/'
session = requests.Session()
session.post(FORUM_URL + 'login.php?do=login', {
    'vb_login_username':        username,
    'vb_login_password':        password,
    'vb_login_md5password':     hashlib.md5(password.encode()).hexdigest(),
    'vb_login_md5password_utf': hashlib.md5(password.encode()).hexdigest(),
    'cookieuser': 1,
    'do': 'login',
    's': '',
    'securitytoken': 'guest'
})
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

q = session.get("https://forumurl.com/forum/showthread.php?123456")
print(str(q.text))
```

This generates the following output: (translated)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
<noscript>
<p>Javascript and Cookies need to be enabled</p>
</noscript>
<script>
createCookie("test", "md5hashofcookie");
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
        if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

</script>
```

After this I tried to do the login with firefoxdriver, which also gets the output above.

I also tried to do it with mechanize and used the following code:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('user-agent', '  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0'),
('accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')]

br.open("https://testforum.com/forum/login.php?do=login")

br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
br["vb_login_username"] = username
br["vb_login_password"] = password
br["vb_login_md5password"] = hashlib.md5(password.encode()).hexdigest()
br["vb_login_md5password_utf"] = hashlib.md5(password.encode()).hexdigest()
br["cookieuser"] = 1
br["do"] = "login"
br["s"] = ""
br["securitytoken"] = "guest"

response = br.submit()
print(response)
```

This generates the following output:

```
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error refresh: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
OK
```

I don't know how to do the login with cookies/javascript enabled.

Edit:

I got the solution with Selenium:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://12345.com/forum/forum.php")
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Login").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("loginbutton").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("vb_login_username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id("vb_login_password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("button").click()
```

Comment: If javascripts is required for the site then the requests package won't work. I have never used mechanize, but looking at the documentation it looks like it is also not able to do javascript. Selenium will work with javascript so you could use that instead.

Comment: i already tried Selenium and Webdriver/Firefox.. it wasnt sucessfull :s

Comment: Can you post your code from when you used Selenium? Selenium should work.

Comment: I've edited the Selenium code and now it works for me :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, forgot to mark it as answered.

Here is the code again:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://12345.com/forum/forum.php")
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Login").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("loginbutton").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("vb_login_username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id("vb_login_password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("button").click()
```